# AngularJS: How to scale repetitive but slightly-dynamic content

Tags: angularjs

I need to implement a browser-like banner warning system so that the user can only access certain features after they've acknowledged certain warnings. The warning messages will depend on data sent from the server and I have to implement different styles and links.

**Edit**: There could be any number of warnings displayed at the same time. One for each feature. The user must individually acknowledge each warning before the corresponding feature is enabled. Some of the warning texts are static, some are dynamic. Some can have different acknowledge links instead of the standard "okay".

[image: Firefox banner]

Traditionally, I would package each kind of warning into a class (in the OO sense) and push them to screen through a centralized method, e.g.

```
displayWarning(new InfoBanner("You must ... before you can modify " + data.name, function onclick() { ... }));
```

Here the InfoBanner class will have a method that creates the banner elements and attach the event handler.

The Angular way of doing this, on the other hand, seems to be you write the banner entirely in HTML with `ng-if` and `ng-click`, etc. E.g.:

```
<p style="info banner" ng-if="...">You must ... before you can modify {{...}}. <a href ng-click="...">Okay</a></p>
```

However, this seems quite unfocused and messy because there will now be a large blob of banner code dwarfing the functional part of the page. (There are hundreds of error types defined!)

Is there any way to resolve this without reverting to the fully imperative code?

(Note: a custom directive is probably not the answer as `<p style="info banner"` is almost like a directive and there's little sharable code among these warnings beyond this.)

(Edit: One can see this question in another way: in the imperative world, the warning-adding logic are scattered in the code but close to the feature they're protecting, so they're easy to understand and maintain. In the declarative world, they must be centralized to the place where they're displayed. I would like a solution where they're declared close to the component they're protecting but displayed centrally.)

Comment: I'm not sure i really understand what you try to achieve. What part of the banner will change ? Only the message ? Is there any case where there will be two banner at the same time or is this banner unique ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your scenario is? What should your warnings do? Are they a kind of confirmations to the user or info that certain actions are disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question your problem is that since you are in an Angular application you need / should include your banners as markup in your HTML view, since however whether each banner is displayed or not depends on the data you are getting from the server you only know if a specific banner should be displayed in your controller (hence the `ng-if` you have included in your banner HTML example).

What I would propose in this case would be to create a BannerService which would hold a list of all the banners that should be displayed at any given time. In your controller you can use the functions exposed by the service to add banners to the list when the data you got from the server indicates that you should do so. Each banner in the list would be an object containing all the information that might be different between different banners (ex. banner text, type, etc.) meaning that your HTML view doesn't really need to "know" anything about specific banner details and can just display all the banners available in the BannerService using an `ng-repeat`.

You can see below a quick-and-dirty example to better understand how this would work.

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', [])

app.service('BannerService', [function(){
  var banners = [];
  
  this.getBanners = function() {
    return banners;
  }
  
  this.addBanner = function(banner) {
    banners.push(banner);
  }
}])

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['BannerService', function(BannerService) {
  // Add banners to the banner service depending on your data etc.
  BannerService.addBanner({text: "This is a banner", type: "info"});
}])

app.controller('BannerCtrl', ['$scope', 'BannerService', function($scope, BannerService) {
  $scope.banners = []
  $scope.$watch('BannerService.getBanners', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    $scope.banners = BannerService.getBanners();
  });
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="BannerCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="banner in banners"><p class="banner {{banner.type}}">{{banner.text}}</p></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">Page content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think loading all the banners upfront is a good solution as there can be many. A better approach would be for each action to provide a certain *banner key* (could be its template URL) and load that on demand. There're `$templateRequest` and `$templateCache` services that help in this regard. I'd use these instead of loading everything.

Comment: What I'm proposing is not to load everything but to use the BannerService to specify the banners that should be displayed in the page (obviously it would have to be extended with additional functions, such as remove to remove a banner after the user has dismissed it). I don't really see how loading the banners that should be displayed in the page could be avoided.

Comment: Right. It wasn't clear from your answer as you said "*...you need/should include your banners as markup in your HTML view*". As these banners have various different behaviours they'll likely come with their own controllers to provide such execution differences and capabilities.

Comment: Yes, I guess this depends on the specific functionality that the OP is trying to provide. I'm sure that my answer could be extended to better fit his specific needs, it should however give him a pretty good starting point.

Comment: So this is one of the things I considered. Problem is it does not look angular anymore (probably cleaner if implemented in jQuery alone) and is very unsafe (handling HTML as string). I'll use this as a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: You don't need to handle the HTML as string (I don't like this either). You can include enough string properties in the banner object to construct the necessary HTML in your view or, if the HTML for different banners is completely different, use templates and include in the banner object the URL of the banner template. As far as whether it looks like Angular is concerned it does look like Angular to me in the sense that it is clear in your view that what you are displaying is a list of banners and implement the actual login in the controller. I get however that this can be a bit subjective.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you are looking to implement fits perfectly with Aspect Oriented Programming. If you've never used AOP before be prepared for some light reading. The concept is simple and works very well with Angular's patterns. There is an AngularAOP project, but before you dive into it I suggest running through this article first:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2425-decorating-scope-methods-in-the-angularjs-prototype-chain.htm

Comment: The blog post you are linking to assumes that you have a hierarchy of scopes and uses it to communicate between the scope controllers. This is in general discouraged by Angular whose proposed solution is to use services in order to exchange data between controllers. One of the reasons why (other than producing unmaintainable code) is that this example will not work if the OP's application structure is such that does not allow nesting the necessary controllers within one another.

Comment: I can see your point about $scope here. While the article was offered more for it's view regarding AOP, you're absolutely right that controllerAs is a best practice in AngularJS.  
... Why did I link that article? I really have no clue. It has nothing to do with what I intended. My apologies @billc.cn , here's a much more relevant article: http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/08/07/aspect-oriented-programming-with-javascript-angularjs/